# Wrap Numbers in Brackets using javascript .replace regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have this String that I am trying to wrap Brackets around the arrays of numbers following 
'Position' and Color.

> str = 'Label_3_1:{Position: 115,234,Width: 126,Height:
>   20,Text:"Another Button",FontSize: 18,Color: 0,0,0,1}'

I can use this regex to do it, but only if the numbers have a space after each comma

```
str = str.replace(/([\d\.]+(, [\d\.]+)+)/g, "[$1]");
```

I am trying to make it work without any spaces.

Output should look like this

```
str = 'Label_3_1:{Position: 115,234,Width: 126,Height: 20,Text:"Another Button",FontSize: 18,Color: [0, 0, 0, 1] }'
```

Comment: Where's that string coming from? If possible send the string encoded as JSON and then decode in JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by add `\s*`, it works

`str.replace(/([\d\.]+(,\s*[\d\.]+)+)/g, "[$1]");`

And this is the result:

`"Label_3_1:{Position: [115,234],Width: 126,Height: 20,Text:"Another Button",FontSize: 18,Color: [0,0,0,1]}"`